# PHP copy only files ending with letters AUW

Tags: php, copy

I have this PHP code to copy files from one directory to another and it works GREAT, however, how do I copy ONLY files ending with the letters "AUW" (minus quotes)? Keep in mind that the file is extensionless so it really ends with the letters AUW.

Also after copying I don't want the files to be deleted from the source folder.

```
// Get array of all source files
$files = scandir("sourcefolder");
// Identify directories
$source = "sourcefolder/";
$destination = "destinationfolder/";
// Cycle through all source files
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
    $delete[] = $source.$file;
  }
}
// Delete all successfully-copied files
foreach ($delete as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
  if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
  if (!endsWith($file, "AUW")) continue;
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
    // comment the following line will not add the files to the delete array and they will
    // not be deleted
    // $delete[] = $source.$file;
  }
}

// comment the followig line of code since we dont want to delete
// anything
// foreach ($delete as $file) {
//   unlink($file);
// }

function endsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    $length = strlen($needle);
    if ($length == 0) return true;

    return (substr($haystack, -$length) === $needle);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment because I am having trouble with new lines and code tags. Your code is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the function [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php).

```
foreach (glob("*AUW") as $filename) {
   // do the work...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `glob` function.

```
foreach( glob( "*.AUW" ) as $filename )
{
      echo $filename;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

Use the [substr() method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to grab the last three letters of the filename. That will return a string that can be used in a logical comparison.

```
if( substr( $file, -3 ) == 'AUW' )
{
  // Process files according to your exception.
}
else
{
  // If we copied this successfully, mark it for deletion
  if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
    $delete[] = $source.$file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is a Google search too hard? 
Ill give you a hint - use `substr()` to see if the last 3 letters are "AUW"

AH

Comment: That's good, but how do I use substr with foreach in my case?